# Local systems on algebraic groups

Tags: sheaf-theory, algebraic-groups

Two questions about local systems:

Given an algebraic group G over a perfect field $k$ and given a colection of vectorial spaces $(F_y)_{y\in G}$ why there is an unique local system $F$ such that the stalk of $F$ in $y\in G$ is $F_y$?

Given a local sistem $F$ and consider an morphism $f:G\rightarrow G$ (in my case is the frobenius morphism) why there is an unique isomorphism (up to scaling) $\phi$ such that: $\phi:(f)^*F \rightarrow F$

Comment: What do you mean by stalk?  If you mean the pullback to the point, then you probably want all the vector spaces to be the same dimension... and in this case all vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, and you're not insisting on any gluing data, so this is trivially true.  If you mean stalk in the usual limit sense, then F_y should be thought of as a module over G_y, not a vector space.

Comment: by stalk i mean 
$F_x := \varinjlim_{U\ni x} F(U)$

how do i see F_y as a module over G_y (what is G_y)

Comment: G_y = lim O_G(U) as above, in the Zariski topology.  The stalk as you define it in the Zariski topology is not the "geometric" fiber.